# HTML - Corp and re-size SVG Image

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a following svg from which I want to display only one icon and re-size it

[image]

I visited couple of [posts](http://cssglobe.com/3-easy-and-fast-css-techniques-for-faux-image/), but none of them is working for me.

I tried by following way:

```
<p class="crop"><img src="/WebNew/Content/main_page_assets/02_general_alerts_icons.svg"/></p>
.crop {
    float: left;
    margin: .5em 10px .5em 0;
    overflow: hidden; /* this is important */
    position: relative; /* this is important too */
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 150px;
    height: 90px;
}

.crop img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: -55px;
}
```

It would be great If somebody can help me with a working fiddle!

Comment: needs to be a css ``content=""`` and background as svg

Comment: looks perfect here. Just increase `.crop img { width: 400%; }` or whatever size to fit screen. also resize `.crop { width: 90px; }` so it's a square, instead of an unecessary rectangle

Answer (score 0):

SVG sprite sheet can easily use like this way:

```
<use xlink:href="#icon-pacman"></use>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xL8d31n9/

It's easier than css sprite sheet does.

Ref: https://css-tricks.com/svg-use-external-source/

Comment: That absolutely not answering my question. Read the question, I have an svg with many icons, i want to cut the one i want using `corp` or whatever and re-size to the size i want

Comment: @omriman12 Why you need css crop way? but not use svg way? svg can also resize to what you want,